# Maximo UI SQL Select Month

Tags: sql, oracle, maximo

I am trying to write a query using SQL in the Maximo 7.5 UI advanced search function which will return data from the month before the month in which the query was run. I want to save this query and make it available to users who will run the query without editing it. For example, if a user ran the saved query on 1/25/2019, the query would return all records for which the date was any day in December 2018. I have previously used "where actfinish >= sysdate-30" but the length on months varies and I cannot rely on the users (who do not write SQL) to always run the query on the first day of each month, so I need the query to filter by the previous month. The field I am filtering on is a DATE field, but in the DB it looks like DD-MMM-YY.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please provide your table schema, sample data, and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Your current `where actfinish >= sysdate-30` will return data from the current month, as well as the issues you mentioned.

You can do something like:

```
where actfinish >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1)
and actfinish < trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
```

The `trunc(sysdate, 'MM')` gives you midnight on the first day of the current month. The first clausesubtracts a month from that, so gives you midnight on the first day of the previous month; the second clause prevent any record from this month being included.

You can check what those evaluate to by querying the terms outside your real query:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

select sysdate,
  add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) as month_from,
  trunc(sysdate, 'MM') as month_to
from dual;

SYSDATE             MONTH_FROM          MONTH_TO           
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2019-01-25 12:59:53 2018-12-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 00:00:00
```

The `alter session` is just to make the client format the results in a particular way, instead of explicitly doing `to_char()`.

When you said "in the DB it looks like DD-MMM-YY", it doesn't actually look like that in the database; when you query the date values your client is formatting the dates like that, so your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is probably set to the still-default DD-MON-RR model. (And it's MON in Oracle, not MMM - see [the format model elements in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A).)

Comment: Thanks, Alex, for the detailed answer and the explanation. I'll give that a try right now.

Comment: Since you are truncating the sysdate wouldn't `between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) and trunc(sysdate, 'MM')` work as well?

Comment: @Sun - `between` is inclusive, so you would include data for exactly midnight on the first day of the current month. Or in other words, that would be the same as `... and actfinish <= trunc(sysdate, 'MM')`. The difference is `<=` versus `<`.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will depend on the type of database that is being used.

For SQL Server, we have used logic along the following lines:

actfinish between dateadd(day,1,eomonth(dateadd(month,-2,getdate()))) and eomonth(dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))

(identify the last day of the previous month and the last day of the month before that + 1 day)

For Oracle, the equivalent would be:

trunc(actfinish,'MONTH') = add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH'),-1)

(identify the year and month associated with last month and compare that against the target date components - trunc month function removes the time and day of month components so making comparisons easier)

Answer (score 0):

> I have previously used "where actfinish >= sysdate-30" but the length
>   on months varies.

By "length of month", do you mean the number of days for each month (e.g. 30, 31, 28, 29) or just a formatting issue with the month? If I understood your question correctly, you can convert the date to character then convert that to date and Oracle will take care of the change in the number of days. For example, something like:

*where to_date(to_char(actfinish, 'mm/dd/yyyy')) >= to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy'))-30*

or

*where to_date(to_char(actfinish), 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= to_date(to_char(sysdate), 'mm/dd/yyyy')-30*

I don't have Maximo installed on my personal laptop so you can try the two I listed above.

Comment: You seem to be modifying the wrong thing - the column value instead of the filter date. I don't think this is what the OP wants, as it will exclude *all* records if run later in the months; and will stop an index on the column being used. And you're relying on the session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT for this to work - if it happens to not be mm/dd/yyyy then you can get errors or wrong results. You could supply the same format mask for the `to_char()`, but `trunc(<date>, 'MM')` is simpler.

Comment: I forgot to include that the sysdate needs to be formatted as well with the to_char and to_date so they match the format. But I will try your suggestion as soon as I install the application in my laptop. Always happy to learn new things. Thank you.